# Header repeats on the second page but no data

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My report has a Header, footer and body with Matrix which displays the data from database. When I print it prints 3 pages. The second page prints header and footer but it didn't print any data from Matrix. The third page is OK again. What could be the problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The textbox width is causing this issue in the footer.